# Как убрать фокус с input после успешной отправки формы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery('input').focus(function() {
  const label = $(this).parent().parent().find('label');
  if (jQuery(this).val()=='') {
  label.animate({
    'top': '5px',
    'font-size': '75%',
  });
  } 
})
jQuery('input').focusout(function() {
    const label = $(this).parent().parent().find('label');
    console.log('Value ', jQuery(this).val());
     if (jQuery(this).val() != '') return;
    console.log('Passed if');
    label.animate({
      'font-size': '17px',
      'top': '10px',
    });

})

document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  alert("ok");
       const label = jQuery("label"); // надо, чтобы он взял все инпуты с фокусом и поставил лэйблы обратно при успешной отправки. Focusout 
       label.animate({
          'font-size': '17px!important',
          'top': '10px!important',
        });




}, false );
```

Когда я нажимаю на input то лэйбл поднимается, когда нажимаю за пределы input то label опускается. Когда успешно отсылаю сообщение, то поля становятся внутри пустыми , а label обратно не возвращается.

`document.addEventListener` alert после отправки выводит , так что на успешную отправку формы реагирует.

Comment: Такие вещи лучше делать на css, а не на js. Но в целом попробуйте `jQuery('input').trigger('blur')`.

Comment: не помогло. Я знаю , что на css , но мне надо было на js

Answer (score 0):

!important лишний

```
label.animate({
    'font-size': '17px',
    'top': '10px',
  });
```

Comment: да я уже решил проблему. Я взял по классу ```.input-label ``` и ему прописал нужные стили после отправки